# How to resolve Sagepay payment gateway error, "4006 : The TxType requested is not supported on this account"?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, opayo, payment-services

On submit form on Live site i got below Error.

Status: INVALID

Status Detail: 4006 : The TxType requested is not supported on this account.

My sagepay setting is for LIVE are below,

SAGEPAY_CONNECT_TO = 'LIVE'; 
SAGEPAY_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'PAYMENT';

but its not working. Some people say it change to 'DEFERRED' but it also not working.
above setting working fine in TEST mode, for TEST mode settings are,

SAGEPAY_CONNECT_TO = 'TEST'; 
SAGEPAY_TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'PAYMENT';

How can i resolve this issue? Can any one help me?

Comment: Is your Live account activated for payment? SagePay need to do this before you go live, and it depends on your test account having performed satisfactory test transactions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone else having the same problem, this is not an issue on the code. You need to contact SagePay and ask them to activate your accout for either 'PAYMENT' OR 'DEFFERED'

Answer (score 0):

We had to ensure we had these Transaction types added when integrating using Omnipay

TX AUTHENTICATE
TX AUTHORISE
TX TOKEN

We were also a MOTO service so that had to be added as well.